# ASP.NET DataSet Queries - Warning is causing DataSet to not fill correctly

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, dataset, warnings, modulus

I've created a DataSet in ASP.NET and replaced the default Fill query with the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT        Resolved_Request.ResolvedReqID, 

In_Progress_Request.DateAssigned, Resolved_Request.DateResolved, Fix(((DATEDIFF('n', 
                         In_Progress_Request.DateAssigned, Resolved_Request.DateResolved) / 60 / 24))) & ' days, ' & ((DATEDIFF('n', In_Progress_Request.DateAssigned, 
                         Resolved_Request.DateResolved) / 60) Mod 24) & ' hours and ' & (DATEDIFF('n', In_Progress_Request.DateAssigned, Resolved_Request.DateResolved) Mod 60) 
                         & ' minutes' AS [Time Spent Resolving], Resolved_Request.SpecialNotes, Resolved_Request.ResolutionSatisfaction, Resolved_Request.RequestID, 
                         Request.RequestID
FROM            ((Resolved_Request INNER JOIN
                         Request ON Resolved_Request.RequestID = Request.RequestID) INNER JOIN
                         In_Progress_Request ON Request.RequestID = In_Progress_Request.RequestID)
ORDER BY Resolved_Request.ResolvedReqID
```

It's a real mess of a statement, but the main focus is on the Fix() part of the query that contains 3 DateDiff functions calculating time between two fields in days, then hours then minutes. I'm using MS Access syntax here since the DB I'm querying is an Access DB file. My issue is that whenever I execute the query I get this:

[image: Error message]

This is simply a warning, once I click OK the query executes and I get the exact results I need. It has never been an issue in Query Builder, but when comes time to create the query in my DataSet, since there is an error the dataset refuses to fill properly. I get this error message when I attempt to add the query to my dataset.

[image: Error message 2]

The SQL stays in the query, since this is only a warning, however all those extra fields that were added via the JOIN commands in my query do not show up in the dataset, I'm assuming because it has that error.

How do I fix this? Why will it not recognize 'Mod', yet the query executes without error and gives me the right output? How do I get it to completely ignore the warning and add the fields to my dataset regardless?

Comment: I suspect, like ```nz()```, ```mod``` is a builtin that is not supported in the .NET data access classes. You could run some simple tests to find out. You could try using math functions such as CInt() to simulate ```mod```'s behaviour. Sorry, some ideas here but no real solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around the warnings being thrown by .NET by generating the query's columns in my DataSet (taking the query with Mod in it, removing it then executing the query). This way the columns are properly filled. ASP.NET was not letting me generate the columns due to the Mod in the query.

Once the columns were generated, I pasted the query with Mod in it. It still threw a warning, but since the columns were all properly generated the report was filled correctly.